# SwiftUI - How to properly use ShareLink to share a multipage PDF that was generated using PDFKit

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16

I am attempting to use `ShareLink` to share a multipage PDF that I created using `PDFKit`. I have it sort of working but not 100%. My code so far is as follows:

The extension I'm using to conform item (PDF) to `Transferable`:

```
extension PDFDocument: Transferable {
    public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .pdf) { pdf in 
            return pdf.dataRepresentation() ?? Data()
        }
    }
}
```

`ShareLink` call:

```
let pdfToShare = PDFDocument(data: myData)
ShareLink(item: pdfToShare ?? PDFDocument(), preview: SharePreview(Text("Sharing - \(docRemName)"), image: Image(uiImage: docRemImage)))
```

When I click the share button, I can use the ShareSheet that displays to share via message and email with no problems. I can even use "Save to Files". However, using other ShareSheet options that pop up like Print, Markup, Copy, or using with another app (Pinterest, Twitter, or whatever) doesn't seem to work. It seems like using things on the ShareSheet is hit or miss. For example, nothing happens when I click "Print" but when I click "Print with HP Smart" (I have an HP printer), it pulls up the preview and I can then print if I wish.

***Anyway, I'm wondering if there is a way to limit what options pop up in the ShareSheet so that it doesn't look like my app is broken if the user picks some of these options.***

***I'm also wondering if I've shared a PDF correctly.*** I've looked at many examples using ShareLink, read the Apple doc, and tried a few YouTube tutorials on this as well. I'm not finding too much regarding specifics about sharing a PDF. Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up not attempting to use the Transferable extension above at all. There may be a way to do this also but given the way my app now functions, I found it to be more effective to just use ShareLink to point to a local file url (url already conforms to Transferable) where the pdf that was created has been previously saved. Example:

```
ShareLink("Share?", item: model.url, subject: Text("subject"), message: Text("message"))
```